# FFMPEG How do I use the apad filter in a chain of filters in filter_complex?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

My input is a video file with an audio track. If the audio is shorter than the video I need to extend the audio track to the length of the video. It works great with the apad filter:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i INPUT -filter_complex "[0:1]apad" -shortest OUTPUT
```

But I need to use other filters, so I made a chain of filters like this (without apad):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i INPUT -y -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=(iw*sar)*(1080/ih):1080:flags=lanczos[scaledv];[scaledv]setpts=((24000/1001)/24)*PTS[outv];[0:a]atempo=(24/(24000/1001))[outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vcodec prores -profile:v 3 -qscale:v 5 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -r "24" OUTPUT
```

When I add the apad filter to the chain, ffmpeg will not stop encoding and I have to close the command line window to make it stop. I tried to put it in the front of the audio filter chain and in the end. Both times it did not work.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i INPUT -y -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=(iw*sar)*(1080/ih):1080:flags=lanczos[scaledv];[scaledv]setpts=((25)/25)*PTS[outv];[0:a]apad[a];[a]atempo=(25/(25))[outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vcodec prores -profile:v 3 -qscale:v 5 -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -r "25" -shortest OUTPUT
```

In my first code example above I used "[0:1]apad", but in the filter chain this did not work, so I tried [0:a]apad. This does not seem to be the correct way, because the encoding never stops. So what is the correct way to use the apad filter in a filter chain like mine above?

Console output (as you can see the last frame was being processed over and over again until I canceled the job):

```
 ffmpeg version N-69375-g4155f2d Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 28 2015 22:14:02 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 21.101 / 56. 21.101
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  9.101 /  5.  9.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'G:\01_dcp_pipeline\00_source_files\input_25fps.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2015-02-01T11:20:05+01:00
    encoder         : Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 (Windows)
  Duration: 00:02:45.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 623634 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (IYUV / 0x56555949), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 622230 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
Output #0, mov, to 'G:\01_dcp_pipeline\00_source_files\output_25fps.mov':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2015-02-01T11:20:05+01:00
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: prores (apch) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.21.101 prores
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32, 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.21.101 pcm_s24le
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (rawvideo) -> scale
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s16le) -> apad
  setpts -> Stream #0:0 (prores)
  atempo -> Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   17 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=     517kB time=00:00:00.95 bitrate=4421.9kbits/s    
frame=   30 fps= 30 q=0.0 size=     986kB time=00:00:01.95 bitrate=4126.9kbits/s    
frame=   44 fps= 29 q=0.0 size=    1565kB time=00:00:01.95 bitrate=6549.3kbits/s    
frame=   57 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=    2043kB time=00:00:02.95 bitrate=5659.9kbits/s    
frame=   73 fps= 29 q=0.0 size=    2640kB time=00:00:02.95 bitrate=7313.6kbits/s    
frame=   88 fps= 29 q=0.0 size=    3666kB time=00:00:03.95 bitrate=7588.4kbits/s    
frame=  100 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=    4757kB time=00:00:03.95 bitrate=9847.7kbits/s    
frame=  113 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=   10978kB time=00:00:04.95 bitrate=18141.3kbits/s    
frame=  125 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=   23403kB time=00:00:04.95 bitrate=38673.9kbits/s    
frame=  140 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=   43077kB time=00:00:05.95 bitrate=59235.2kbits/s    
frame=  154 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=   60810kB time=00:00:06.93 bitrate=71822.1kbits/s    
frame=  168 fps= 28 q=0.0 size=   79878kB time=00:00:06.93 bitrate=94342.8kbits/s    
frame=  177 fps= 27 q=0.0 size=   92109kB time=00:00:07.95 bitrate=94825.4kbits/s    
frame=  187 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=  105743kB time=00:00:07.95 bitrate=108861.0kbits/s    
frame=  199 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=  122070kB time=00:00:07.95 bitrate=125670.3kbits/s    
frame=  211 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=  138499kB time=00:00:08.95 bitrate=126665.1kbits/s    
frame=  221 fps= 26 q=0.0 size=  152110kB time=00:00:08.95 bitrate=139113.4kbits/s    
frame=  230 fps= 25 q=0.0 size=  164367kB time=00:00:09.95 bitrate=135226.5kbits/s    
frame=  240 fps= 25 q=0.0 size=  177853kB time=00:00:09.95 bitrate=146321.2kbits/s    
frame=  250 fps= 25 q=0.0 size=  191401kB time=00:00:09.95 bitrate=157467.6kbits/s    
frame=  260 fps= 24 q=0.0 size=  204960kB time=00:00:10.95 bitrate=153233.8kbits/s    
frame=  271 fps= 24 q=0.0 size=  219944kB time=00:00:10.95 bitrate=164436.0kbits/s    
frame=  283 fps= 24 q=0.0 size=  236327kB time=00:00:11.95 bitrate=161908.2kbits/s    
frame=  294 fps= 23 q=0.0 size=  251324kB time=00:00:11.95 bitrate=172182.5kbits/s    
frame=  305 fps= 23 q=0.0 size=  266381kB time=00:00:12.95 bitrate=168413.5kbits/s    
frame=  315 fps= 23 q=0.0 size=  280051kB time=00:00:12.95 bitrate=177056.1kbits/s    
frame=  325 fps= 23 q=0.0 size=  293665kB time=00:00:12.95 bitrate=185663.2kbits/s    
frame=  332 fps= 23 q=0.0 size=  303265kB time=00:00:13.95 bitrate=177995.7kbits/s    
frame=  341 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  315593kB time=00:00:13.95 bitrate=185231.5kbits/s    
frame=  350 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  327856kB time=00:00:13.99 bitrate=191878.9kbits/s    
frame=  364 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  346888kB time=00:00:14.93 bitrate=190259.0kbits/s    
frame=  375 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  361949kB time=00:00:14.93 bitrate=198519.6kbits/s    
frame=  387 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  378319kB time=00:00:15.93 bitrate=194444.8kbits/s    
frame=  398 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  393382kB time=00:00:15.93 bitrate=202186.9kbits/s    
frame=  408 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  407134kB time=00:00:16.96 bitrate=196653.3kbits/s    
frame=  418 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  420803kB time=00:00:16.96 bitrate=203255.9kbits/s    
frame=  429 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  435834kB time=00:00:17.96 bitrate=198794.7kbits/s    
frame=  438 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  448150kB time=00:00:17.96 bitrate=204412.5kbits/s    
frame=  446 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  459033kB time=00:00:17.96 bitrate=209376.2kbits/s    
frame=  457 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  474020kB time=00:00:18.96 bitrate=204808.5kbits/s    
frame=  466 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  486336kB time=00:00:18.96 bitrate=210129.9kbits/s    
frame=  475 fps= 22 q=0.0 size=  498719kB time=00:00:18.97 bitrate=215268.5kbits/s    
frame=  485 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  512314kB time=00:00:19.96 bitrate=210264.5kbits/s    
frame=  494 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  524594kB time=00:00:19.96 bitrate=215304.1kbits/s    
frame=  504 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  538306kB time=00:00:20.96 bitrate=210391.2kbits/s    
frame=  515 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  553274kB time=00:00:20.96 bitrate=216241.4kbits/s    
frame=  525 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  566879kB time=00:00:20.97 bitrate=221361.6kbits/s    
frame=  537 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  583210kB time=00:00:21.96 bitrate=217561.7kbits/s    
frame=  546 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  595457kB time=00:00:21.96 bitrate=222130.5kbits/s    
frame=  554 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  606407kB time=00:00:22.93 bitrate=216563.7kbits/s    
frame=  564 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  620056kB time=00:00:22.93 bitrate=221438.3kbits/s    
frame=  575 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  635064kB time=00:00:22.93 bitrate=226798.0kbits/s    
frame=  588 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  652824kB time=00:00:23.93 bitrate=223401.6kbits/s    
frame=  599 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  667878kB time=00:00:23.93 bitrate=228552.9kbits/s    
frame=  608 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  680135kB time=00:00:24.96 bitrate=223223.9kbits/s    
frame=  619 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  695133kB time=00:00:24.96 bitrate=228146.3kbits/s    
frame=  630 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  710153kB time=00:00:25.96 bitrate=224097.5kbits/s    
frame=  641 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  725071kB time=00:00:25.96 bitrate=228805.0kbits/s    
frame=  649 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  735965kB time=00:00:25.96 bitrate=232242.8kbits/s    
frame=  659 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  749595kB time=00:00:26.96 bitrate=227770.1kbits/s    
frame=  670 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  764562kB time=00:00:26.96 bitrate=232317.8kbits/s    
frame=  680 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  778127kB time=00:00:27.96 bitrate=227983.5kbits/s    
frame=  690 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  791805kB time=00:00:27.96 bitrate=231990.9kbits/s    
frame=  699 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  804195kB time=00:00:27.96 bitrate=235621.1kbits/s    
frame=  709 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  817942kB time=00:00:28.96 bitrate=231373.6kbits/s    
frame=  719 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  831697kB time=00:00:28.96 bitrate=235264.6kbits/s    
frame=  729 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  845428kB time=00:00:29.96 bitrate=231166.4kbits/s    
frame=  740 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  860513kB time=00:00:29.96 bitrate=235291.2kbits/s    
frame=  750 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  874265kB time=00:00:29.97 bitrate=238902.6kbits/s    
frame=  762 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  890768kB time=00:00:30.93 bitrate=235859.3kbits/s    
frame=  771 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  903118kB time=00:00:30.93 bitrate=239129.3kbits/s    
frame=  781 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  916847kB time=00:00:31.94 bitrate=235144.0kbits/s    
frame=  792 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  931932kB time=00:00:31.94 bitrate=239012.8kbits/s    
frame=  803 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  947043kB time=00:00:32.96 bitrate=235381.5kbits/s    
frame=  815 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  963489kB time=00:00:32.96 bitrate=239469.2kbits/s    
frame=  825 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  977213kB time=00:00:32.96 bitrate=242880.2kbits/s    
frame=  835 fps= 21 q=0.0 size=  990951kB time=00:00:33.96 bitrate=239042.2kbits/s    
frame=  847 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1007412kB time=00:00:33.96 bitrate=243013.0kbits/s    
frame=  856 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1019777kB time=00:00:34.96 bitrate=238959.3kbits/s    
frame=  866 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1033523kB time=00:00:34.96 bitrate=242180.1kbits/s    
frame=  875 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1045886kB time=00:00:34.97 bitrate=244946.4kbits/s    
frame=  884 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1058245kB time=00:00:35.96 bitrate=241077.4kbits/s    
frame=  895 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1073358kB time=00:00:35.96 bitrate=244520.3kbits/s    
frame=  906 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1088443kB time=00:00:36.96 bitrate=241248.0kbits/s    
frame=  916 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1102151kB time=00:00:36.96 bitrate=244286.2kbits/s    
frame=  925 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1114495kB time=00:00:36.97 bitrate=246897.6kbits/s    
frame=  936 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1129604kB time=00:00:37.96 bitrate=243775.6kbits/s    
frame=  946 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1143335kB time=00:00:37.96 bitrate=246738.7kbits/s    
frame=  958 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1159800kB time=00:00:38.93 bitrate=244001.2kbits/s    
frame=  969 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1174857kB time=00:00:38.93 bitrate=247168.9kbits/s    
frame=  979 fps= 21 q=0.0 size= 1188674kB time=00:00:39.94 bitrate=243798.0kbits/s    
frame=  989 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1202484kB time=00:00:39.94 bitrate=246630.5kbits/s    
frame=  996 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1212163kB time=00:00:39.94 bitrate=248615.6kbits/s    
frame= 1006 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1225924kB time=00:00:40.96 bitrate=245184.8kbits/s    
frame= 1015 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1238363kB time=00:00:40.96 bitrate=247672.7kbits/s    
frame= 1025 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1252209kB time=00:00:40.98 bitrate=250311.4kbits/s    
frame= 1035 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1266030kB time=00:00:41.96 bitrate=247171.5kbits/s    
frame= 1047 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1282623kB time=00:00:41.96 bitrate=250411.0kbits/s    
frame= 1055 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1293688kB time=00:00:42.96 bitrate=246692.2kbits/s    
frame= 1067 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1310319kB time=00:00:42.96 bitrate=249863.4kbits/s    
frame= 1077 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1324125kB time=00:00:43.96 bitrate=246752.3kbits/s    
frame= 1087 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1337867kB time=00:00:43.96 bitrate=249313.1kbits/s    
frame= 1097 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1351680kB time=00:00:43.96 bitrate=251887.2kbits/s    
frame= 1107 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1365488kB time=00:00:44.96 bitrate=248800.7kbits/s    
frame= 1117 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1379316kB time=00:00:44.96 bitrate=251320.3kbits/s    
frame= 1128 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1394516kB time=00:00:45.96 bitrate=248561.2kbits/s    
frame= 1139 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1409734kB time=00:00:45.96 bitrate=251273.8kbits/s    
frame= 1150 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1424961kB time=00:00:45.96 bitrate=253987.9kbits/s    
frame= 1160 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1438786kB time=00:00:46.93 bitrate=251105.0kbits/s    
frame= 1170 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1452602kB time=00:00:46.93 bitrate=253516.2kbits/s    
frame= 1181 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1467782kB time=00:00:47.94 bitrate=250808.1kbits/s    
frame= 1191 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1481581kB time=00:00:47.94 bitrate=253166.0kbits/s    
frame= 1200 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1494063kB time=00:00:47.96 bitrate=255199.4kbits/s    
frame= 1211 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1509335kB time=00:00:48.96 bitrate=252542.3kbits/s    
frame= 1220 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1521790kB time=00:00:48.96 bitrate=254626.3kbits/s    
frame= 1230 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1535573kB time=00:00:49.96 bitrate=251789.7kbits/s    
frame= 1241 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1550740kB time=00:00:49.96 bitrate=254276.6kbits/s    
frame= 1252 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1565872kB time=00:00:50.96 bitrate=251719.4kbits/s    
frame= 1263 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1581063kB time=00:00:50.96 bitrate=254161.5kbits/s    
frame= 1275 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1597594kB time=00:00:50.96 bitrate=256818.9kbits/s    
frame= 1285 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1611381kB time=00:00:51.96 bitrate=254049.9kbits/s    
frame= 1295 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1625135kB time=00:00:51.96 bitrate=256218.4kbits/s    
frame= 1304 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1637536kB time=00:00:52.96 bitrate=253298.7kbits/s    
frame= 1314 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1651317kB time=00:00:52.96 bitrate=255430.3kbits/s    
frame= 1322 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1662340kB time=00:00:52.96 bitrate=257135.4kbits/s    
frame= 1333 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1677447kB time=00:00:53.96 bitrate=254663.6kbits/s    
frame= 1344 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1692569kB time=00:00:53.96 bitrate=256959.3kbits/s    
frame= 1355 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1707808kB time=00:00:54.93 bitrate=254654.3kbits/s    
frame= 1364 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1720259kB time=00:00:54.93 bitrate=256510.8kbits/s    
frame= 1372 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1731320kB time=00:00:54.93 bitrate=258160.1kbits/s    
frame= 1383 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1746491kB time=00:00:55.93 bitrate=255766.8kbits/s    
frame= 1393 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1760335kB time=00:00:55.93 bitrate=257794.2kbits/s    
frame= 1403 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1774199kB time=00:00:56.96 bitrate=255165.6kbits/s    
frame= 1414 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1789442kB time=00:00:56.96 bitrate=257357.9kbits/s    
frame= 1424 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1803284kB time=00:00:56.96 bitrate=259348.8kbits/s    
frame= 1433 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1815726kB time=00:00:57.96 bitrate=256632.7kbits/s    
frame= 1443 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1829577kB time=00:00:57.96 bitrate=258590.3kbits/s    
frame= 1453 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1843467kB time=00:00:58.96 bitrate=256134.4kbits/s    
frame= 1463 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1857340kB time=00:00:58.96 bitrate=258061.9kbits/s    
frame= 1474 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1872575kB time=00:00:58.96 bitrate=260178.7kbits/s    
frame= 1484 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1886447kB time=00:00:59.96 bitrate=257734.7kbits/s    
frame= 1494 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1900220kB time=00:00:59.96 bitrate=259616.5kbits/s    
frame= 1505 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1915276kB time=00:01:00.96 bitrate=257380.9kbits/s    
frame= 1515 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1928924kB time=00:01:00.96 bitrate=259214.9kbits/s    
frame= 1524 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1941213kB time=00:01:00.96 bitrate=260866.5kbits/s    
frame= 1535 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1956242kB time=00:01:01.96 bitrate=258643.2kbits/s    
frame= 1544 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1968548kB time=00:01:01.96 bitrate=260270.2kbits/s    
frame= 1555 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1983636kB time=00:01:02.93 bitrate=258187.0kbits/s    
frame= 1565 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 1997415kB time=00:01:02.93 bitrate=259980.5kbits/s    
frame= 1577 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2013976kB time=00:01:03.93 bitrate=258036.2kbits/s    
frame= 1586 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2026386kB time=00:01:03.93 bitrate=259626.2kbits/s    
frame= 1597 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2041558kB time=00:01:03.93 bitrate=261570.1kbits/s    
frame= 1606 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2053967kB time=00:01:04.96 bitrate=259022.5kbits/s    
frame= 1618 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2070522kB time=00:01:04.96 bitrate=261110.2kbits/s    
frame= 1627 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2082942kB time=00:01:05.96 bitrate=258694.1kbits/s    
frame= 1638 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2098126kB time=00:01:05.96 bitrate=260579.8kbits/s    
frame= 1647 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2110499kB time=00:01:05.96 bitrate=262116.6kbits/s    
frame= 1658 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2125820kB time=00:01:06.96 bitrate=260076.5kbits/s    
frame= 1668 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2139749kB time=00:01:06.96 bitrate=261780.5kbits/s    
frame= 1675 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2149490kB time=00:01:06.97 bitrate=262899.0kbits/s    
frame= 1687 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2166102kB time=00:01:07.96 bitrate=261105.2kbits/s    
frame= 1698 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2181368kB time=00:01:07.96 bitrate=262945.4kbits/s    
frame= 1710 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2198119kB time=00:01:08.96 bitrate=261122.2kbits/s    
frame= 1722 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2214846kB time=00:01:08.96 bitrate=263109.4kbits/s    
frame= 1732 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2228794kB time=00:01:09.93 bitrate=261061.3kbits/s    
frame= 1742 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2242785kB time=00:01:09.93 bitrate=262700.1kbits/s    
frame= 1752 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2256814kB time=00:01:10.94 bitrate=260607.2kbits/s    
frame= 1759 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2266636kB time=00:01:10.94 bitrate=261741.4kbits/s    
frame= 1770 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2282069kB time=00:01:10.94 bitrate=263523.5kbits/s    
frame= 1780 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2296066kB time=00:01:11.94 bitrate=261454.3kbits/s    
frame= 1791 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2311431kB time=00:01:11.94 bitrate=263203.9kbits/s    
frame= 1800 fps= 20 q=0.0 size= 2324039kB time=00:01:11.94 bitrate=264639.6kbits/s      
frame= 3533 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4710703kB time=00:02:21.96 bitrate=271837.7kbits/s    
frame= 3540 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4720336kB time=00:02:21.96 bitrate=272393.6kbits/s    
frame= 3548 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4731281kB time=00:02:21.96 bitrate=273025.2kbits/s    
frame= 3555 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4740895kB time=00:02:22.96 bitrate=271666.3kbits/s    
frame= 3563 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4751947kB time=00:02:22.96 bitrate=272299.6kbits/s    
frame= 3570 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4761501kB time=00:02:22.96 bitrate=272847.1kbits/s    
frame= 3575 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4768294kB time=00:02:23.14 bitrate=272874.9kbits/s    
frame= 3585 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4782008kB time=00:02:23.93 bitrate=272159.0kbits/s    
frame= 3592 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4791713kB time=00:02:23.93 bitrate=272711.4kbits/s    
frame= 3600 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4802534kB time=00:02:23.93 bitrate=273327.3kbits/s    
frame= 3608 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4813463kB time=00:02:24.96 bitrate=272019.1kbits/s    
frame= 3615 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4823050kB time=00:02:24.96 bitrate=272560.9kbits/s    
frame= 3621 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4831324kB time=00:02:24.96 bitrate=273028.5kbits/s    
frame= 3625 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4836784kB time=00:02:24.98 bitrate=273296.8kbits/s    
frame= 3635 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4850596kB time=00:02:25.96 bitrate=272239.5kbits/s    
frame= 3642 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4860252kB time=00:02:25.96 bitrate=272781.5kbits/s    
frame= 3649 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4869844kB time=00:02:25.96 bitrate=273319.8kbits/s    
frame= 3656 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4879451kB time=00:02:26.96 bitrate=271995.5kbits/s    
frame= 3662 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4887646kB time=00:02:26.96 bitrate=272452.3kbits/s    
frame= 3671 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4900043kB time=00:02:26.96 bitrate=273143.4kbits/s    
frame= 3675 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4905479kB time=00:02:27.46 bitrate=272502.0kbits/s    
frame= 3685 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4919221kB time=00:02:27.96 bitrate=272359.1kbits/s    
frame= 3692 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4928754kB time=00:02:27.96 bitrate=272886.9kbits/s    
frame= 3698 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4937023kB time=00:02:27.96 bitrate=273344.7kbits/s    
frame= 3703 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4943832kB time=00:02:28.96 bitrate=271884.2kbits/s    
frame= 3712 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4956205kB time=00:02:28.96 bitrate=272564.7kbits/s    
frame= 3720 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4967043kB time=00:02:28.96 bitrate=273160.7kbits/s    
frame= 3727 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4976600kB time=00:02:29.96 bitrate=271861.2kbits/s    
frame= 3735 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4987545kB time=00:02:29.96 bitrate=272459.1kbits/s    
frame= 3742 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 4996999kB time=00:02:29.96 bitrate=272975.6kbits/s    
frame= 3750 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5008040kB time=00:02:29.96 bitrate=273578.7kbits/s    
frame= 3756 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5016184kB time=00:02:30.96 bitrate=272208.4kbits/s    
frame= 3764 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5027112kB time=00:02:30.96 bitrate=272801.4kbits/s    
frame= 3771 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5036597kB time=00:02:30.96 bitrate=273316.1kbits/s    
frame= 3777 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5044777kB time=00:02:31.93 bitrate=271996.7kbits/s    
frame= 3786 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5056876kB time=00:02:31.93 bitrate=272649.0kbits/s    
frame= 3794 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5067757kB time=00:02:31.93 bitrate=273235.7kbits/s    
frame= 3800 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5075906kB time=00:02:31.98 bitrate=273598.2kbits/s    
frame= 3807 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5085372kB time=00:02:32.96 bitrate=272354.7kbits/s    
frame= 3815 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5096288kB time=00:02:32.96 bitrate=272939.3kbits/s    
frame= 3822 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5105807kB time=00:02:32.96 bitrate=273449.1kbits/s    
frame= 3828 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5114032kB time=00:02:33.96 bitrate=272110.6kbits/s    
frame= 3837 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5126252kB time=00:02:33.96 bitrate=272760.8kbits/s    
frame= 3844 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5135822kB time=00:02:33.96 bitrate=273270.0kbits/s    
frame= 3850 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5144021kB time=00:02:33.96 bitrate=273706.3kbits/s    
frame= 3857 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5153597kB time=00:02:34.96 bitrate=272446.2kbits/s    
frame= 3865 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5164641kB time=00:02:34.96 bitrate=273030.1kbits/s    
frame= 3872 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5174082kB time=00:02:34.96 bitrate=273529.2kbits/s    
frame= 3878 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5182310kB time=00:02:35.96 bitrate=272207.5kbits/s    
frame= 3886 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5193255kB time=00:02:35.96 bitrate=272782.4kbits/s    
frame= 3894 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5204205kB time=00:02:35.96 bitrate=273357.6kbits/s    
frame= 3900 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5212302kB time=00:02:35.97 bitrate=273750.1kbits/s    
frame= 3908 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5223216kB time=00:02:36.96 bitrate=272608.2kbits/s    
frame= 3914 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5231411kB time=00:02:36.96 bitrate=273035.9kbits/s    
frame= 3922 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5242366kB time=00:02:36.96 bitrate=273607.7kbits/s    
frame= 3929 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5251923kB time=00:02:37.96 bitrate=272371.2kbits/s    
frame= 3936 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5261443kB time=00:02:37.96 bitrate=272864.9kbits/s    
frame= 3944 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5272434kB time=00:02:37.96 bitrate=273434.9kbits/s    
frame= 3950 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5280621kB time=00:02:38.32 bitrate=273236.8kbits/s    
frame= 3958 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5291486kB time=00:02:38.93 bitrate=272733.2kbits/s    
frame= 3966 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5302096kB time=00:02:38.93 bitrate=273280.1kbits/s    
frame= 3973 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5309109kB time=00:02:38.93 bitrate=273641.6kbits/s    
frame= 3982 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5312083kB time=00:02:39.94 bitrate=272078.4kbits/s    
frame= 3992 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5312408kB time=00:02:39.94 bitrate=272095.1kbits/s    
frame= 4003 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5312766kB time=00:02:40.96 bitrate=270391.3kbits/s    
frame= 4013 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5313213kB time=00:02:40.96 bitrate=270414.0kbits/s    
frame= 4024 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5314242kB time=00:02:40.96 bitrate=270466.4kbits/s    
frame= 4033 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5315086kB time=00:02:41.96 bitrate=268839.1kbits/s    
frame= 4043 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5316026kB time=00:02:41.96 bitrate=268886.7kbits/s    
frame= 4054 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5317061kB time=00:02:42.96 bitrate=267288.7kbits/s    
frame= 4064 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5318000kB time=00:02:42.96 bitrate=267335.9kbits/s    
frame= 4075 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5319028kB time=00:02:42.96 bitrate=267387.6kbits/s    
frame= 4084 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5319873kB time=00:02:43.96 bitrate=265799.0kbits/s    
frame= 4094 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5320813kB time=00:02:43.96 bitrate=265845.9kbits/s    
frame= 4105 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5321848kB time=00:02:44.96 bitrate=264285.7kbits/s    
frame= 4114 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5322692kB time=00:02:44.96 bitrate=264327.7kbits/s    
frame= 4122 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5323443kB time=00:02:44.96 bitrate=264365.0kbits/s    
frame= 4132 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5324376kB time=00:02:45.55 bitrate=263461.6kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5328943kB time=00:03:08.95 bitrate=231029.4kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5385559kB time=00:06:30.25 bitrate=113049.4kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5446279kB time=00:10:06.15 bitrate=73605.2kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5506039kB time=00:13:38.63 bitrate=55098.6kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5566711kB time=00:17:14.35 bitrate=44087.9kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5623807kB time=00:20:37.36 bitrate=37232.6kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5683807kB time=00:24:10.69 bitrate=32096.1kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5739103kB time=00:27:27.30 bitrate=28540.4kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5797567kB time=00:30:55.17 bitrate=25600.6kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5854567kB time=00:34:17.84 bitrate=23306.3kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5914231kB time=00:37:49.98 bitrate=21343.5kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 5965783kB time=00:40:53.27 bitrate=19921.0kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 6013783kB time=00:43:43.94 bitrate=18775.1kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 16 q=0.0 size= 6059791kB time=00:46:27.52 bitrate=17808.5kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 15 q=0.0 size= 6108223kB time=00:49:19.73 bitrate=16906.5kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 15 q=0.0 size= 6148663kB time=00:51:43.51 bitrate=16229.9kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 15 q=0.0 size= 6201055kB time=00:54:49.80 bitrate=15441.4kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 15 q=0.0 size= 6250159kB time=00:57:44.39 bitrate=14779.3kbits/s    
frame= 4140 fps= 15 q=0.0 size= 6301135kB time=01:00:45.64 bitrate=14159.1kbits/s
```

Comment: Please add the complete console output for your last command. You can use `-t 30` to make a 30 second output for testing, or whatever value is necessary for proper testing.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about the -t flag! I added the console output to my post.

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this same problem. I have an audio filter graph for doing `adelay` or `atrim` operations. And when I try to added an `apad` filter (with `-shortest` flag), it also will continue encoding forever.